# Java launch independent process

Tags: java, process, parent-child

I have a java app from which I run console based programs on linux system, I am reading the output of those programs and then my java app is sending it to a webpage.

But once I close my java app all the processes will get "stuck" or they just simply crash. So everytime I want to make some changes to my java app and I need to restart it I also have to close all processes that were running from my app. I would like to save their PIDs when closing my app and then take control (output streams) over those processes again based on saved PIDs of the processes.

Is there any way to do it?

I am running my programs like this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "su", "-
s", "/bin/sh", "myuser", "-c", "java -jar myjar.jar" });,
Process p = processBuilder.start();
```

Edit:

My problem is not finding the process PID my problem is that my subprocesses lanched from my java app are crashing after my java app is closed/terminated and I need them to continue running even while my app is restarting/stopped.

Comment: On unix.stackexchange, I found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process can you confirm that this solves your issue, and then I will close your question here as duplicate?

Comment: Nope this does not solve my issue, its java related not terminal related. I need to "separate" my process in java not in terminal. I need somehow change the way I am launching my process from java app. Thats what I am asking help for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is due to what is called **Unix job control**.

Like many shells do, `/bin/sh` intercepts SIGHUP and SIGINT signals, and before exiting, it sends signals to some of its child processes groups, depending on its configuration and on their state (for instance, stopped background processes receive a SIGCONT).

So, when your main java app is closed, the `/bin/sh` shell that your app had forked is terminated, and just before exiting, it sends a SIGHUP signal to its subprocesses corresponding to the command `java -jar myjar.jar`.

So, the answer to your question is: **just use the `huponexit` /bin/sh shell option to avoid killing subprocesses**. They will be detached from the controlling terminal, if any, but they will not be killed.

So, replace this `java -jar myjar.jar` by `shopt -u huponexit; java -jar myjar.jar`:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder =
  new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {
    "su", "-s", "/bin/sh", "myuser", "-c",
    "shopt -u huponexit; java -jar myjar.jar"
  });
Process p = processBuilder.start();
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I needed, now I can restart my app without the need of closing all subprocesses and keep them running and then take control over them after I start my app again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run your command like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gedit");
```

It executes the specified string command in a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I have found some useful information [here](http://www.golesny.de/p/code/javagetpid). Try this.

Comment: Just idea - I didn't try it. In linux env you can try to use 'nohup' command.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ps command in Linux to get the number of each process(s) running which you want to control, of course you would execute it just as you have above with your ProcessBuilder. I would then pipe; "|" (Linux Command), the output into a file you have saved somewhere in your Java project.

The Linux command to execute from your Java program would look something a long the lines of

ps -A | grep "your_program_name" > /path/to/your/project/my_process_list_file.txt

Where the > stores the output of the command executed to your file.

I would then read from this file and execute some other Linux commands to take control of that process in whichever way you desire.

Good Luck, and happy coding my friend!

Comment: Thanks fro answer, however thats not exactly my problem, I have eddited my post. Please look at it, thank you :)

Comment: Ah, I see! I figured I wasn't touching exactly the right base with my answer. None the less I hope you got some benefit from it. In addition, this question actually helped me solve a problem is my own programs I didn't even know I was experiencing, so thanks for asking!